# How to avoid overhead of continuous ajax request on keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

e.g. In a search form when user enter some text, at that time, AJAX request should send on each keyup event, with search key as query string. Search key will be value from input box.

If user enters "ABCD", in this case first 3 AJAX request should get kill/cancel, because in 4th AJAX request searchkey will be "ABCD"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchInput").keyup(function(){
        ajaxSearch( $("#searchInput").val() );
    });
});
```

On keyup event I am calling following "ajaxSearch()" function.

```
function ajaxSearch(searchKey) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://example.com/ajaxRequestHandler/",
        data: "action=search&searchkey=" + searchKey
    }).done(function() {
        /* process response */
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var request;
function ajaxSearch(searchKey) {
    /* if request is in-process, kill it */
    if(request) {
        request.abort();
    };

    request = $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://example.com/ajaxRequestHandler/",
        data: "action=search&searchkey=" + searchKey
    }).done(function() {
        /* process response */

        /* response received, reset variable */
        request = null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To avoid multiple ajax requests; we can refer and implement a debounce function as mentioned in [David Walsh's Blog post.](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) It has some great insights of debounce function implementation from [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/). The Debounce function will only fire once every fraction of a second instead of as quickly as it's triggered. It surely helps to restrict continuous network requests.

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

var ajaxSearch = debounce(function(searchKey) {
 //send an AJAX network request.
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://example.com/ajaxRequestHandler/",
        data: "action=search&searchkey=" + searchKey
    }).done(function() {
        /* process response */
    });
 //250 indicates the minimum time interval between the series of events being fired
}, 250);

$("#searchInput").keyup(function(){
    ajaxSearch($("#searchInput").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of Atul Bhosale there are still four request, when the user is typing "ABCD". It is only a question of typing speed and response time of the server.

It would be better to use a timeout. In this case the request is just send if the user "finished/takes a timeout" typing:

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function(){ 
    var value = $(this).val();
    setTimeout( function() { ajaxSearch(value) }, 300 );
});
```

Just play around with the timeout. For me 300ms are fine...

Comment: This would work, but considering if the server takes 5 seconds to return the data, during these 5 seconds, you can process 5000/300 requests depending on the keyup delay, that would cause all sort of problems if not properly handled. So you need a way of aborting the previous request when another keyup event is fired.